# get localised list of country names based on codes

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list of country codes for which I want to get the list of localised country names based on the code.

I have written a function to return localised country name based on code which is in a for loop.

So for each item in the list I go through this for loop and return an item.

Is there a way to simplify this?

I go through `countryList` and for each `it.countryCode` I pass it to `getLocalisedCountryNameForCode()` function which has a for loop.

```
   private fun getLocalisedCountriesList(countryList: List<CountryDTO>): List<WelcomeScreenCountry> {
    testCountriesList(countryList)
    return countryList.map {
        Timber.d("xxxx BE code: ${it.countryCode} - countryName: ${it.countryName}")
        WelcomeScreenCountry(
                getLocalisedCountryNameForCode(it.countryCode),
                it.countryCode
        )
    }
}



private fun getLocalisedCountryNameForCode(countryCode: String): String {
        val isoCountries = Locale.getISOCountries()
        for (country in isoCountries) {
            val locale = Locale("en", country)
            val iso = locale.isO3Country
            val code = locale.country
            val name = locale.displayCountry
            println("$iso $code $name")
            if(code == countryCode) {
                return name
            }
            Timber.d("xxxx ISO:  $iso - code: $code - name: $name")
        }
        return "none"
    }
```